# Zipping with padding in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

A couple of times I've found myself wanting a `zip` in Haskell that adds padding to the shorter list instead of truncating the longer one. This is easy enough to write. (`Monoid` works for me here, but you could also just pass in the elements that you want to use for padding.)

```
zipPad :: (Monoid a, Monoid b) => [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
zipPad xs [] = zip xs (repeat mempty)
zipPad [] ys = zip (repeat mempty) ys
zipPad (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x, y) : zipPad xs ys
```

This approach gets ugly when trying to define `zipPad3`. I typed up the following and then realized that of course it doesn't work:

```
zipPad3 :: (Monoid a, Monoid b, Monoid c) => [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a, b, c)]
zipPad3 xs [] [] = zip3 xs (repeat mempty) (repeat mempty)
zipPad3 [] ys [] = zip3 (repeat mempty) ys (repeat mempty)
zipPad3 [] [] zs = zip3 (repeat mempty) (repeat mempty) zs
zipPad3 xs ys [] = zip3 xs ys (repeat mempty)
zipPad3 xs [] zs = zip3 xs (repeat mempty) zs
zipPad3 [] ys zs = zip3 (repeat mempty) ys zs
zipPad3 (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs) = (x, y, z) : zipPad3 xs ys zs
```

At this point I cheated and just used `length` to pick the longest list and pad the others.

Am I overlooking a more elegant way to do this, or is something like `zipPad3` already defined somewhere?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about custom `head` and `tail` functions (named `next` and `rest` in my example below)?

```
import Data.Monoid

zipPad :: (Monoid a, Monoid b) => [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zipPad [] [] = []
zipPad xs ys = (next xs, next ys) : zipPad (rest xs) (rest ys)

zipPad3 :: (Monoid a, Monoid b, Monoid c) => [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a,b,c)]
zipPad3 [] [] [] = []
zipPad3 xs ys zs = (next xs, next ys, next zs) : zipPad3 (rest xs) (rest ys) (rest zs)

next :: (Monoid a) => [a] -> a
next [] = mempty
next xs = head xs

rest :: (Monoid a) => [a] -> [a]
rest [] = []
rest xs = tail xs
```

Test snippet:

```
instance Monoid Int where
  mempty = 0
  mappend = (+)

main = do
  print $ zipPad [1,2,3,4 :: Int] [1,2 :: Int]
  print $ zipPad3 [1,2,3,4 :: Int] [9 :: Int] [1,2 :: Int]
```

Its output:

```
[(1,1),(2,2),(3,0),(4,0)]
[(1,9,1),(2,0,2),(3,0,0),(4,0,0)]
```

Answer (score 12):

This pattern comes up quite a lot. A solution I learned from [Paul Chiusano](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com/) is as follows:

```
data These a b = This a | That b | These a b

class Align f where
  align :: (These a b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c

instance Align [] where
  align f []     []     = []
  align f (x:xs) []     = f (This x)    : align f xs []
  align f []     (y:ys) = f (That y)    : align f [] ys
  align f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f (These x y) : align f xs ys

liftAlign2 f a b = align t
  where t (This l)    = f l b
        t (That r)    = f a r
        t (These l r) = f l r

zipPad a b = liftAlign2 (,) a b

liftAlign3 f a b c xs ys = align t (zipPad a b xs ys)
  where t (This  (x,y))   = f x y c
        t (That  r)       = f a b r
        t (These (x,y) r) = f x y r

zipPad3 a b c = liftAlign3 (,,) a b c
```

A little test in ghci:

```
 *Main> zipPad3 ["foo", "bar", "baz"] [2, 4, 6, 8] [True, False] "" 0 False
 [("foo",2,True),("bar",4,False),("baz",6,False),("",8,False)]
```

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way to do this is with `Maybe`. I will illustrate with Edward's
more general formulation:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Applicative

zipWithTails l r f as bs = catMaybes . takeWhile isJust $
    zipWith fMaybe (extend as) (extend bs)
  where
    extend xs = map Just xs ++ repeat Nothing
    fMaybe a b = liftA2 f a b <|> fmap l a <|> fmap r b
```

Answer (score 3):

There are times when you want to be able to apply a different function to either tail rather than just supply `mempty` or manual zeroes as well:

```
zipWithTail :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipWithTail f (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : zipWithTails f as bs
zipWithTail f [] bs = bs
zipWithTail f as _ = as

zipWithTails :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithTails l r f (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : zipWithTails l r f as bs
zipWithTails _ r _ [] bs = fmap r bs
zipWithTails l _ _ as _ = fmap l as
```

I use the former when I'm doing something like `zipWithTail (+)`
and the former when I need to do something like `zipWithTail (*b) (a*) (\da db -> a*db+b*da)` since the former can be much more efficient than feeding a default into a function, and the latter a little bit so.

However, if you just wanted to make a more succinct version of what you have, you could probably turn to mapAccumL ,but its not any clearer, and the ++ can be expensive.

```
zipPad as bs = done $ mapAccumL go as bs
    where go (a:as) b = (as,(a,b))
          go [] b = ([],(mempty,b))
          done (cs, both) = both ++ fmap (\x -> (x, mempty)) cs
```