# Projecting of zipped streams to the longest stream

Tags: scala

The built-in zip functions on Stream appear to truncate at the shortest of the pair of input streams. How can I implement this function:

```
def firstOrLongest[T]( a : Stream[ T ], b : Stream[ T ) : Stream[ T ]
// resulting stream should have the property that:
// while there are still elements of a, return (the corresponding element of) a 
// else return (the corresponding element of) b.
```

Comment: See the answers to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3015962/334519) for some solutions to a similar problem in Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zipAll` method to extend the shorter collection to the length of the longer. This method involves creation of many intermediate objects.

```
def firstOrLongest[T]( a : Stream[T], b : Stream[T]) : Stream[T] = {
  val oa = a.map{ e => Some(e): Option[T] }
  val ob = b.map{ e => Some(e): Option[T] }
  oa.zipAll(ob, None, None).collect{
    case (Some(e), _) => e
    case (None, Some(e)) => e
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Stream class has an append operator that does exactly what you want.

Your description states:

```
// while there are still elements of a, return (the corresponding element of) a 
// else return (the corresponding element of) b.
```

In Scala, that's just:

```
a ++ b
```