# How to combine two lists of different sizes

Tags: scala, collections

How to combine two `List` of different sizes ?

For example `merge(List("a", "b"), List("1", "2", "3"), "")`
should return `List(("a, "1"), ("b", "2"), ("", "3"))`

Here is my current version :

```
def merge[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A], default: A) : List[(A, A)] = {
    val m = max(l1.size, l2.size)
    l1.padTo(m, default).zip(l2.padTo(m, default))
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: I think your version is fine, but if you want some other ideas, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3015962/334519)'s a related Haskell question I asked a long time ago.

Comment: @EndeNeu my question is for generic `List` and not only `List[String]`. Moreover, I don't mix two concerns : merging the list and combining elements in resulting tuples.

Comment: @YannMoisan you want the same output basically which is a list of tuples with a default for the shorter list, the fact that you want it to be for a generic type doesn't make your question different than that one in my opinion, plus you already know how to do it with generics, in your merge method you also ask for a `default: A` parameter which can be used in `zipAll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zipAll does exactly what you need:

```
def merge[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A], default: A) : List[(A, A)] = {
  l1.zipAll(l2, default, default)
}
```